# How to scrape a database platform like Beauhurst and Pitchbook?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Using python 3.12; pycharm.
A little context: I have just under 800 supposedly UK private equity companies on an excel sheet and a lot of them are inactive/dissolved/etc. I have to capture some key data for each of these firms (some indication of fund size/investment size etc to figure out market positioning, and whether they're in business).

This would take days to parse through if I do it by myself. I am looking to just automatically scrape Beauhurst (I have an account), and/or Pitchbook (using the free profile previews) to find out inactive/active and whether in the UK.

Once the list is shortened down, I'll either scrape different needed data, or then just do other ranking manually.

Onto the problem, I am a beginner-to-some-intermediate python coder, and I've never done web scraping. I have requests (which I know I can use to log into my Beauhurst account), and Beautiful Soup to scrape. Is it actually possible to do what I want to do? The information I'm looking for isn't on one long webpage, it's going to be 700+ webpages, albeit on singular websites.

I have started a practice run on pycharm and so far I've run into a lot of issues setting up code to scrape a singular page because I also have to learn about html. I expected it to work but my structure overall is bad. Before I throw in significant time on this, I want to know if it's worth it/possible with what I've got.

Comment: Please post code of your practice on run on pycharm so we can understand how you're trying to scrape the website. Are you using selenium? Playwright? Scrapy? Personally, if you're a beginner at scraping websites, I would recommend using [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro).